# Assistance with JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, title, caption

I have run into an issue as follows:

I have a piece of JavaScript that stops unsightly link titles popping up on my site.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        link.onmouseover = function() {
            this.setAttribute("org_title", this.title);
            this.title = "";
        };
        link.onmouseout = function() {
            this.title = this.getAttribute("org_title");
        };
    };
};
```

This works perfectly for what I need.

However, now I want to use the Swipebox plugin which uses the "a title" field as a caption. As the title is removed on mouseover, it shows as no caption for the image in the gallery that I clicked on (others in the gallery still show their one).

What I would like to do is, for my JavaScript as above, target all "a" elements that DO NOT have the class "swipebox".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var links = document.querySelectorAll("a:not(.swipebox)");`

Comment: Coolest of all, but won't be supported by IE8.

Comment: @raina77ow `querySelectorAll` is plenty supported by IE8. It's not supported in earlier versions than that. Unless you mean the `:not()` selector?

Comment: No, QSA is supported. `:not` selector isn't, however. Check [this](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/), if you won't believe me, a proud user of IE8 still. ))

Comment: @raina77ow Yep, just looked it up. Thanks for pointing that out. I tend to overlook CSS support for old IE because jQuery normalizes so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        if(link.getAttribute("class").indexOf("swipebox") == -1) {
            link.onmouseover = function() {
                this.setAttribute("org_title", this.title);
                this.title = "";
            };
            link.onmouseout = function() {
                this.title = this.getAttribute("org_title");
            };
        }
    };
};
```

**Edit:** as PlantTheIdea said, using `getAttribute()` in this case makes more sense...

Comment: This worked great, thank you very much. I was getting confused with where to put an if statement within the existing code, and this solved it!

Comment: How come `outerHTML` (which isn't - ok, wasn't, but still - quite cross-platform, afair) is used here instead of `className`?

Comment: @raina77ow Not to mention if **anything** inside the tag contains the text "swipebox", meaning attributes, attribute values, or inner text, this would match. There's such an easier, better-supported, consistent way

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Indeed, thanks for pointing that out, I updated the answer and +1 your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work if included in your loop:

```
if(link.className.indexOf('swipebox') === -1){
    // do your magic
}
```

This will check to see if `swipebox` exists in the element's class(es), and only do the magic if it did not exist.

**EDIT**

Great recommendation by @raina77ow!

```
if(!(/\bswipebox\b/.test(link.className))){
    // do your magic
}
```

RegEx test to make sure swipebox does not exist in any form in the classname. This should cover all your bases quite well.

Comment: don't you just love when some guy just downvotes everyone on the page and then gives no reason as to why? i love a good mystery.

Comment: I think all of these answers didn't deserve the downvotes, so I took care of that ;D

Comment: howderek Nice! and as PlantTheldea says, it's quite a mystery, at least that person should state their reason for being an ass...

Comment: This won't work if there's a class like "swipebox-title". Also, you shouldn't use `.getAttribute()` for getting the `class`...access the `.className` property

Comment: I'd use `/\bswipebox\b/.test(link.className)` here, actually.

Comment: `.getAttribute()` is a bit more universal, works with XML as well. if u can explain some performance benefits, all ears.

Comment: @raina77ow - great idea! added it as another option. and i also edited my answer so that i dont waste any more time bickering about something so trivial as `.className` vs `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea While you're right that `getAttribute` is more "universal", we're talking about HTML, and there's quirks about **specifically getting the class** with `.getAttribute()`, while `.className` is better supported. A quick Google search can easily confirm that. Nontheless, good edit +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following excluding code:

```
if (link.className == null || link.className != "swipebox") {
    [...your two onmouseover/onmouseout functions...]
}
```

Comment: This won't work if there's multiple classes, such as `class="swipebox something-else"`